# allow a shelve object to be pickled in python, pypar and mpich2

Tags: python, json, pickle, mpi, shelve

I have some legacy python code that using pypar and mpich2 to transmit data between multiple nodes.  For some reason the data is kept in shelves and pypar wants to pickle the shelve to send it to other nodes.  Pickling shelves is not allowed.  So I want to convert from shelve to something I can send via pypar which pickles it before sending to other nodes.  Any suggestions?  Could I convert the shelve to json and pickle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the shelve to a `dict()` and then pickling it:

```
sdb = shelve.open('foo.db')
sdb['abc'] = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
tmp = cPickle.dumps(dict(sdb), 2)
print cPickle.loads(tmp)
{'abc': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

**Updated**: (Response to a question in comments): A `dict` can copy the key-values from any mapping object, so if that object implements the methods `keys` and `__getitem__` it will work. Since a shelve is a mapping object, the `dict` copy constructor can read the key-values from the shelve, then you can pickle the resulting dict and ship it to other hosts.

The example below shows the minimal interface `dict` requires to copy an object:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def keys(self):
        return ['a', 'b']

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        v = self.value
        self.value += 1
        return self.value

foo = Foo()
print dict(foo)
print dict(foo)
```

Output

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

**Update**: To add the contents of a dict back to a shelve, use `update()`:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
s = shelve.open('foo.db')
s.update(d)
print s
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: so i just use dict(shelve-object)?

Comment: Yep, the `shelve` is a DictMixin, which means it behaves like a dict, so it can be passed to the constructor of dict which will copy its contents.  I'll updated my answer with more clarification.

Comment: it might be obvious, but how do I turn the dict back to a shelve?

Answer (score 1):

[@samplebias's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268508/allow-a-shelve-object-to-be-pickled-in-python-pypar-and-mpich2/5268742#5268742) of converting your shelve object to a dict will work.

However, (*this may be a long shot but*) considered your data is already shelved to a db file, it might be worth checking if it is faster to have the other nodes load data off the shelve file instead of doing MPI sends. I'm assuming all nodes have access to the same filesystem since you're running them using MPI.

To be honest, I'd expect the MPI send to be faster especially if you're running on a shared-memory system since many MPI implementations will fallback to a memory copy. However, once you include the overheads of repickling and unpickling for the send, the race might be close!

I suspect it will be down to the number of nodes you're running it on, and your communication pattern.